# Compute AIC in Survival Analysis (survfit/coxph)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to compute the AIC value for my survival analysis objects (suvfit/coxph).
When I try to do it, it says:

```
> AIC(cox)
  Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
   no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "coxph"
```

For what I understand that's a software limitation. Can anyone help me to solve this problem without computing the AIC value by hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function `extractAIC` has a method for `coxph`

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = cancer)
extractAIC(fit)
```

Comment: @George Dontas I am experiencing the same problem but with the surfvit() function. The error is the following one  `AIC(fit1)
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "survfit"`

Answer (score 6):

I remember I was computing it by hand, like this

```
p <- 0;k <- 3 
AIC0 <- -2*cox$loglik[1] + 2*(p+k)
p <- length(cox$coef)
AIC1 <- -2*cox$loglik[2] + 2*(p+k)
```